# Reduce the gap between rows when using matplotlib subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My subplot results
[image: subplot]

My code

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(rows,cols, figsize = [24,24])
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, wspace=0)

for i in range(cols):
    step = 6
    ind = i*step
    ax[0,i].imshow(a[ind,:,:],cmap='gray')
    ax[0,i].axis('off')

    ax[1,i].imshow(b[ind,:,:],cmap='gray')
    ax[1,i].axis('off')

    ax[2,i].imshow(c[ind,:,:],cmap='gray')
    ax[2,i].axis('off')
```

However, it seems like plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, wspace=0) not working at all. I notice that it forces the figure to have equal x and y size, could you help me correct this?

Comment: gridspec might help

Comment: or plt.tight_layout()

Answer (score 6):

You may either shrink the figure size in vertical direction, e.g.

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(rows,cols, figsize = [24,12])
```

or you may keep the square figure size but put more margin around the subplots

```
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3, top=0.7, hspace=0)
```

Answer (score 3):

The ratio in figsize should be same as the ratio of rows and cols in `plt.subplot(rows, cols, figsize)`. For example, if rows is 2 and cols is 4, then the ratio is 1/2, thus figsize being (15, 7.5)(same ratio) would be good.

Following code is an example.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize=(15, 7.5))
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(4):
        img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(os.path.join('../input/deepfake486326facescleaned', train_df.loc[i*2+j, 'name_path'])), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        ax[i][j].imshow(img)
        ax[i][j].set_title(train_df.loc[i*2+j, 'label'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have used `figsize=[24,24]` to make it a square image. `subplots_adjust` then makes each `ax[i,j]` to stick to the adjacent one. But `ax.imshow()` does not fill each `ax`. In your sample above, if the vertical size of the image were larger, it would have filled the area alloted to that axes, but by distorting the image. If you want to try that out, use the command `ax[0,i].imshow(a[ind,:,:],cmap='gray', aspect='auto')`: the `aspect='auto'` part will stretch your images to fill the axes. 
If you want the image aspect ratio to not be distorted, then you have to edit your `figsize` accordingly.