# remove white spaces in images subplot in python and save it

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.5, subplot, imshow

I want to create a subplot of spectrograms in python3, using the following code.
My problem is that I have white spaces between plots and

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

j=0
plt.clf()

f, axarr= plt.subplots(4,5, gridspec_kw = {'wspace':0, 'hspace':0})
f.tight_layout()

for i, ax in enumerate(f.axes):
    j=j+1
    im = ax.imshow(syllable_1.transpose(), vmin=0, vmax=syllable_1.max(), 
    cmap='pink_r')

    plt.xticks([], [])

    #ax[j].autoscale_view('tight')

    #ax.set_xticklabels([])

    #ax.set_yticklabels([])


#plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.85, top=0.85, bottom=0.1)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)

plt.savefig("myfig9.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

the result is as follows:

[image]

could you please suggest me some solutions to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to lest you know, I add `aspect='auto'` to my plot code and it is solved. I used the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893450/reduce-the-gap-between-rows-when-using-matplotlib-subplot). It seems that I did not use good keywords for search. Thanks